# Solr sorting with group.sort and sort returns inappropriate order

Tags: sorting, solr

We use solr for our product search. As products we have variants of base products (e.g. a shirt could have variants for the colors red, green, yellow etc.) and each variant is a document in our solr index.

Now we have a requirement to only show one product variant based on a rule set. (1. products in cart, 2. products on sale, 3. lowest price)
I tried to solve this by grouping by a field common to all variants per product (called base_string in this example) and sort the group based on the rule set.
This works fine but when I sort by the price (price_double field) in descending orderi get a unexpected result.

For example if I have this documents:

```
{
    "id": "000101",
    "name_string": "Test 1.1",
    "base_string": "0001",
    "price_double": 11.5,
    "test_boolean": true
},
{
    "id": "000102",
    "name_string": "Test 1.2",
    "base_string": "0001",
    "price_double": 10.5,
    "test_boolean": true
},
{
    "id": "000103",
    "name_string": "Test 1.3",
    "base_string": "0001",
    "price_double": 1.5,
    "test_boolean": true
},
{
    "id": "0002",
    "name_string": "Test 2",
    "base_string": "0002",
    "price_double": 5.5,
    "test_boolean": true
},
{
    "id": "0003",
    "name_string": "Test 3",
    "base_string": "0003",
    "price_double": 55.5,
    "test_boolean": true
}
```

I query the 3 relevant products with following query sorted by price_double in ascending order:

```
q=test_boolean%3Atrue&sort=price_double+asc&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.field=base_string&group.sort=price_double asc
```

The result seems fine (000103 (Price: 1.5), 0002 (Price: 5.5), 0003 (Price 55.5)).

If I sort by price_double in descending order I get a result with a, for me, unlogical order:

```
q=test_boolean%3Atrue&sort=price_double+asc&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.field=base_string&group.sort=price_double desc
```

The result is: 0003 (Price 55.5), 000101 (Price 1.5), 0002 (Price 5.5)

Why do I get a wrong order if I sort by price_double in descending order?
Does the group sort happens after the document sort?

Any ideas how I could solve this?

Comment: What is the field type of price_double? Has it changed since the data was indexed?

Comment: the type of price_double is "solr.TrieDoubleField" and it has not changed. If I sort without grouping the returned order is what I expect of sorting by price (55.5, 11.5, 10.5, 5.5, 1.5).

Comment: try adding debug to your query to see more information about the results. Also, what version of Solr are you using?

Comment: We use version 4.6.1. How can i get debug information about the sorting? debugQuery=true just seem to give information about score calculation and timings?